# change background image of wordpress site

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to change the body background image for a wordpress site but it is not working.

The HTML class is this:

```
<body class="home blog" style>
```

And my CSS is this:

```
body.home.blog{
    background-image:url('http://distilleryimage10.s3.amazonaws.com/0d443332b7bc11e2a7d622000a9e298f_6.jpg');
background-position:right top;
}
```

Does anyone know what CSS to write?

Also this is a wordpress site so keep that in mind. I don't use wordpress or php very often.

Comment: That should work.. can you provide us with a live example demonstrating it not working?

Comment: sure: This is the url http://candyappleblue.co.uk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it..

You are going to want to remove the following line for your 'blue.css' stylesheet:

```
body {
background: #232528;
}
```

The `background-image` is working.. the background color is just being placed over top of it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the following from your `Blue.css` file

```
body {
  background: #232528;
}
```

Or add `!important;` to your background in the file `style.css` like so:

```
body {
  font: 0.75em / 1.73em  Arial,sans-serif;
  color: #6f6f6f;
  background: #211D19;
  background: url('http://distilleryimage10.s3.amazonaws.com/0d443332b7bc11e2a7d622000a9e298f_6.jpg') !important;
  background-position:right top;
}
```

Comment: @JoshC I was typing the rest of the answer... `!important;`

Comment: !important should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: @JoshC yes, but for an ideal solution I'd have to say combine the 6 style sheets

Answer (score 0):

I don't see in your css rule for body.home.blog, only background-image for body without classes. Check your css it's should work